# unexpected null value dart

Tags: flutter, dart

[GitHub Codes](https://github.com/mrshahen/test)

[image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9IHw.png)

unexpected null value

See also :https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

```
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building LoginScreen(dirty, state: _LoginScreenState#64bdd):
```

Unexpected null value.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
LoginScreen file:///C:/Users/Abdelrahman%20Shaheen/AndroidStudioProjects/Salam/salam/lib/main.dart:12:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49      throw*
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 518:63  nullCheck
packages/salam/shared/components/components.dart 38:27                                                                         defaultFormField
packages/salam/modules/login/login_screen.dart 60:19                                                                           build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4691:27                                                                            build
...

Comment: Don't post images, just the code/log error

Comment: This question could use a [repro]. Check out [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for `defaultFormField()` includes nullable arguments `onSubmit` and `onChange`:

```
Widget defaultFormField({
  required TextEditingController controller,
  required TextInputType type,
  required validate,
  required String? label,
  required IconData prefix,
  Function? onSubmit,
  Function? onChange,
}) =>
    TextFormField(
      keyboardType: type,
      obscureText: true,
      onFieldSubmitted: onSubmit!(),
      onChanged: onChange!(),
      validator: validate!(),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: label,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        prefixIcon: Icon(prefix),
        suffixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.remove_red_eye_outlined),
      ),
    );
```

However, you're using the null-check operator (`!`), which will cause a crash if used on a null value. If you want them to be required, you can specify them as required arguments, and make them non-nullable (exclude the question marks in the type declarations).

On the other hand, if they should be optional, you need to check if they're null before using them, like so:

```
Widget defaultFormField({
  required TextEditingController controller,
  required TextInputType type,
  required validate,
  required String? label,
  required IconData prefix,
  Function? onSubmit,
  Function? onChange,
}) =>
    TextFormField(
      keyboardType: type,
      obscureText: true,
      onFieldSubmitted: onSubmit?.call(), // Using ?.call to check if null before calling
      onChanged: onChange?.call(),
      validator: validate?.call(),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: label,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        prefixIcon: Icon(prefix),
        suffixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.remove_red_eye_outlined),
      ),
    );
```

And a last note: It's not necessary to require a nullable argument, as you've required `label` here. If the argument is not given, it will simply be set to null. Of course, if you want to make sure that argument is always explicitly given, even if it's null, then that's fine too. If you want to require that it's given and never null, then you can just remove the question mark.

For more info, see here the sections "Smarter null aware methods" and "Null assertion operator": https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#smarter-null-aware-methods